# Access Master Page class in C# .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, master-pages

So... I'm having to get someone's old (2010) .Net 3.5 C# code working... and of course the dev didn't have the project files anymore just the source...

Long story is code is trying to access a property of the master page class and this looks like it should be working according to everything I can find but it's not.

Example of the MasterPage code behind:

```
public partial class myMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
   private string pageName = "";
   public string PageName
   {
       get { return PageName; }
       set { pageName = value; }
   }

   private int pageID;
   public int PageID
   {
       get { return pageID; }
       set { pageID = value; }
   }
}
```

One of the pages code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Help" Codebehind="Help.aspx.cs" %>
<%@ MasterType TypeName="ISLMasterPage"  %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
```

And finally the code behind for that page:

```
public partial class Help : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.PageID = 1; 
        Master.PageID = 1;  
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the MasterType to virtual path... nothing... error I'm getting is:

> E'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'PageID' and no extension method 'PageID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So to me it's obvious that it's not picking up the fact that we want the code behind.

I'm guessing this is something obvious but I've never organized my code in such a way.

Comment: This look suspicious: `<%@ MasterType TypeName="ISLMasterPage"  %>`. Seems the page expects a derived type as the master page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't know that your master page is a "myMasterPage"

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.PageID = 1; 
    (Master as myMasterPage).PageID = 1;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Works, I figured it was something silly... just about the only thing I didn't try... how the heck this code ever worked is beyond me...

Answer (score 1):

It seems your code has inherited a `BasePage`

```
public partial class Help : BasePage
```

It overrides the normal `System.Web.UI.Page` and enables easy access to properties on every page where `BasePage` is used.

In the BasePage class there could be something like this:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Site master;

    public BasePage()
    {
        this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        master = ((Site)(Page.Master));
    }
}
```

In this example the Master Page is always accessible with `master` on the pages that inherit `BasePage`